# Apache NiFi to/from Confluent Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, confluent-cloud

I'm trying to publish custom db data (derived from Microsoft SQL CDC tables, having a join on other tables -> how it's arrived is for a different day though) to Kafka cluster.

I'm able to publish and consume messages from Apache NiFi -to/from- Apache Kafka.

But I'm unable to do publish messages from Apache NiFi -to- Kafka in Confluent Cloud.

1. Is it possible to publish/consume messages from Apache NiFi (server-A) to Confluent Cloud using the API Key that's created there?
2. If yes, what is the corresponding property in Apache NiFi's PublishKafkaRecord's processor and ConsumeKafkaRecord processor?
3. If no, please share any other idea to overcome the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NiFi uses the [plain Kafka Clients Java API](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/java.html#client-examples-java); it can work with any Kafka environment.

Confluent Cloud gives you all the client properties you will need, such as SASL configs for username + password.

Using [`PublishKafka_2_6`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-6-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafka_2_6/index.html) as an example,

Obviously, "Kafka Brokers" is the Bootstrap Brokers, then you have "Username" and "Password" settings for the SASL connection.

Set "Security Protocol" to `SASL_SSL` and "SASL Mechanism" to `PLAIN`.

"Delivery Guarantee" will set producer `acks`.

For any extra properties, use the `+` button above the properties for setting "Dynamic Properties" (refer above NiFi docs)

---

> share any other idea to overcome the constraint

Use [Debezium (Kafka Connect) instead](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/cloud-etl/docs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. 
Debezium Kafka Connector to connect NiFi and Kafka? 
What’s the advantage over PublishKafka processor?

Comment: No. To stream your data into Kafka without NiFi.

Comment: Thanks, @OneCricketeer. 
I intend to stream the CDC data that’s transposed / left-joined. 
This is possible with apt query on NiFi processor. 
How to get this custom CDC data (join at source) using Debezium?

Comment: Debezium would poll the tables directly rather than any joined views, for example. Therefore, you'd have to use Kafka Stream/KSQL or other processor to join the data within topics